# Can files be downloaded asynchronously? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out why my file downloading action is no longer working. The View is

```
using(Ajax.BeginForm("DownloadFile",
"FileBundle",
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "dwnldFileCallback" }))
{
    <input name="fileName" type="hidden" id="file2Download" />
}
```

which renders out to

```
<form action="/myProject/myController/DownloadFile" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="dwnldFileCallback" id="form1" method="post">        
     <input name="fileName" type="hidden" id="file2Download" />
</form>
```

and the DownloadFile function in myController is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadFile ( string fileName )
{
    if (Session["isAuthenticated"] == "true")
    {
        string fullFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Assets") + "/" + fileName;
        byte[] fileBytes = GetFile(fullFilePath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("Not authenticated");
    }
}
```

and is not getting called. It was getting called back when my View was

```
using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile",
    "FileBundle",
    FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input name="fileName" type="hidden" id="file2Download" />
    }
```

so all I've done is changed it to an asynchronous procedure. Is that something I can do? Or is there something else wrong? Or do I need to post more code for you to see?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the unobtrusive ajax stuff properly enabled:

The jquery lib has to be included on the page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also the following key have to be set under appSettings in web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

[EDIT]
But when i think about it: Do you want to issue a download to the user? If that's what you want, this won't work as communication will happen in an AJAX context so the user will not get prompted for the file.